# FlexBox with 100% height

Tags: css, flexbox

I need to have a 100% height flexbox with just a children footer with 50px.
Is possible without have the calc(100% - 50px) ?

here my try:

```css
body, html{
  height:100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:red;
}

.flex-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-A {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-1-child {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: calc(100% - 50px);
}
.flex-2-child {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
}

.text{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-1">test</div>
    <div class="flex-A">
        <div class="flex-1-child">
            <div class="text">test2</div>
         </div>
        <div class="flex-2-child">
            <div>test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't have the 100% height.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Remove `overflow-y:auto`, is that what you are trying to get?

Comment: no that overflow is ok but the overflow outside shouldn't appear because of the 100%height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `height: calc(100% - 50px);` to `flex: 1;` and it will expand its height maximally.

I guess this is what you want?
https://jsfiddle.net/shuding/3ss44wuk/1

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer but why do i have an overflow in my container?

Comment: @Spawnrad That's because the `.text` element has a 500px height and the container is shorter than that. You could either remove the `500px` or change `overflow-y: auto;` to `overflow-y: hidden;` to avoid the overflow.

Comment: That overflow is ok. I have an other overflow outside this one.

Comment: @Spawnrad I see. That's caused by margins of `body` element. Adding `margin: 0;` to `body` removed this overflow: https://jsfiddle.net/shuding/3ss44wuk/4/

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `flex: 1` on the dynamic element.

```css
body, html{
  height:100%;
}
.container {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color:red;
}

.flex-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-A {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100%;
}

.flex-1-child {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow-y: auto;
    flex: 1;
}
.flex-2-child {
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
}

.text{
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="flex-1">test</div>
    <div class="flex-A">
        <div class="flex-1-child">
            <div class="text">test2</div>
         </div>
        <div class="flex-2-child">
            <div>test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. How can i have my container at 100% height and don't have the overflow ?

Comment: Remove the static height from `.text`. You set it to 500 which is taller than its parent, so the parent will get a scrollbar.

Comment: This one is ok. I don't need the parent scrollbar ( 100% height container without overflow)